# how to checks to see if a separate module is installed use npm?

Tags: npm

npm ls, I have tested, because I use a lot of modules, I would like to know whether a separate module is installed successfully, npm whether there is this order?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can run `npm install`, it will read your package.json, install all modules and gives you a report on what is being installed succesfully or not. You will just have to look for your module name on the list provided in the log.